# android setX() and setY() crash application

Tags: java, android

I'v have a button named 'circle' and Im trying to do when clicked another button, so that circle will placed in x=20,y=20.

so here is the code to do that:

```
circle.setX((float) 20.00);
circle.setY((float) 20.00);
```

but the application has stop running and crashing, but when I delete that 2 line of code, the application work's perfectly.

where is the problem?

Comment: Make sure `circle != null`

Comment: Add your error log to your question. It could help.

Comment: That the thing, there is now error log..

Comment: @NirGofman Are you running the app with the device connected to your development computer? You should be able to see the error in the Logcat.